# How can I set a div's position to the same position as my HTML <body> opening tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, master-pages, positioning

I've got an ASP.NET page with a master page, which for whatever reason causes `top:0; left:0` to be just under the master page. Inspecting my generated DOM, I've found that `<body>` is at the very top of the page, where I need to position the `<div>`. How can I use JQuery to position my `<div>` at the exact same location as my `<body>` tag?

Comment: top and left of what? Some more html/css would be helpful here. Top and Left are relative to the last container that is relative (they are static by default). So this may be the reason why it isn't positioned properly. Hacking around it with jQuery does not sound like the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `top:0` would not actually be the top is that the div must be contained within an element which has `position: relative` or `position: absolute` (more likely, relative).

The easiest way to fix this would be to append the div directly to the body.

```
$("#yourdiv").appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset):

```
$("#myDiv").offset({ top: 0, left: 0 });
```

Your div is being positioned relative to its closest ancestor with `position: relative` or `position: absolute`.  In order to position it relative to the page, you need to compute the total offset and apply that to your div.  `.offset()` does all that for you.

Here's a demo illustrating what is going on: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/trSkC/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").css($("body").offset());
```

Comment: `$("body").offset()` returns (essentially) whatever the body margins are.  If you have `body { margin: 25px; }`, then `$("body").offset()` returns `{ top: 25, left: 25 }`.  If the div has a relatively positioned ancestor, (which seems to be the case) this will position it 25px from the top left of that ancestor - not the page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in your CSS?

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```